# How to refresh a database query using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm working on a real basic chat that is mostly php powered. I'd like to use jQuery to check for new messages and update the `#cbox` div every few seconds. So far I have tried accomplishing that using the code below. For a frame of reference, this is my first time including jQuery into any of my scripts, so the problem is likely a very simple error that I am overlooking in my newbishness.

The problem I'm running into is the `#cbox` div displays blank, it doesn't seem to be calling to `chat_post.php` at all. I will post that code as well, in case the problem is with that and not with my jQuery. To fix, I tried also including `<div id='cbox'>` in `chat_post.php`, but that yielded no results. At this point, I'm pretty much grasping at straws.

```
<div id='sb_content'>
    <center><div id='chat'>

        <div id='ribbon' style='position: relative; margin-top:-50px; margin-left:-32px;'><center><span class='ribbon'>chat box</span></center></div>
        <div style='margin-top: -20px;'><center><span style='text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #000;' class='admin'>admin</span> || <span style='text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #000;' class='mod'>mod</span></center></div>

        <div id="cbox">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function(){getUpdates()}, 2000); 
        });

        function getUpdates() {
            $("#cbox").load("chat_post.php");
        }
        </script>
        </div>

        <form name="message" method='post' action="chat_post.php" id="cbox_input">
            <input name="usermsg"id='usermsg' type="text" size="63" maxlength="255" />
        </form>

    </div></center>
    </div>
```

chat_post.php

```
<div id='cbox' align='left'>

<?php

$username = $_SESSION['login'];
$ug = $_SESSION['user_group'];


// Display messages
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM `chat_entries`
ORDER BY `ts` DESC
LIMIT 0,50
SQL;

$result = $db->query($sql);
$count = $result->num_rows;

if ($count != 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $c_name = $row['author'];
            $c_text = $row['text'];
            $c_ts = $row['ts'];
            $c_id = $row['id'];

$sqlm = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE username = '$c_name'
SQL;

            $resultm = $db->query($sqlm);
            $countm = $resultm->num_rows;

            if ($count != 0){
                while ($rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($resultm)) {
                    $c_level = $rowm['user_group'];
                }
            }

            if ($c_level == 'mod') {
                echo "
                <a href='/user/" . $c_name . "' class='mod'>" . $c_name . "</a>
                ";
            }

            if ($c_level == 'admin') {
                echo "
                <a href='/user/" . $c_name . "' class='admin'>" . $c_name . "</a>
                ";
            }

            if ($c_level == 'member') {
                echo "
                <a href='/user/" . $c_name . "' class='member'>" . $c_name . "</a>
                ";
            }

            if ($c_level == 'guest') {
                echo "
                <i>" . $c_name . "</i>
                ";
            }

            echo "
            : " . $c_text . "<div id='cbox_div'>";

            echo "<span style='float:left;'><i>" . $c_ts . "</i></span>";

            echo "<span style='float:right;'>";

            if ($ug == 'mod' || $ug == 'admin'){
                echo " <a href='#'>Delete</a> || <a href='#'>Block</a> ||";
            }

            if ($_SESSION['login']) {
                echo "<a href=/report/?type=chat?id=" . $c_id . ">Report</a></span></div>
                ";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: On your `chat_post.php`, try `print_r($_SESSION);` after the `session_start()`see if it at least populates with that.

Comment: Inspect actual requests in browser console dev tools network tab for status response etc

Comment: @Rasclatt No dice, still blank. When I go manually to the page, it displays the chat messages fine, it just won't populate in the div correctly.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @Rasclatt Nope, none. :\

Comment: Paste this, check that it's at least working: `$(document).ready(function() {
           console.log('test'); setInterval(function(){getUpdates()}, 2000); 
        });`

Comment: Paste to see if your function is firing: `function getUpdates() {
            console.log(Math.random()); $("#cbox").load("chat_post.php");
        }`

Comment: @Rasclatt I posted where my current jQuery and that worked.

Comment: Can't duplicate ID's in page, they are unique by defintiion...make sure to remove the one in chat.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the extra id on `chat_post.php`, my code worked just fine. Funny how something so simple can really mess things up. (: Thank you everyone for your help!